# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, syntax

I'm trying to run a "py" file from ubuntu terminal (by calling a script file with ./run_dlc_filter_predictions.py)

This line within the code is throwing a syntax error near unexpected token '(' - that I'm receiving in the terminal.

```
import pathlib
project_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
```

Any idea how to fix it? The syntax seems perfectly fine to me. I spent hours trying to figure it out, and no idea. What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: You need to add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line or you need to call with `python3 ./run_dlc_filter_predictions.py`. By default linux will try to execute a script using /bin/sh if you do not specify a shebang.

Comment: Oh my god, I knew it's gonna be something like that. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

If already installed, ya can call “python3” the script name, so it’ll run too.

```
python3 run_dlc_filter_predictions.py
```